# ¿Cómo validar solo 2 decimales en un input en tiempo real?

Tags: reactjs

Tengo un input en el cual quiero validar que no se le pueda escribir mas de 2 decimales

```
<input id={"IDpayvalue"} name={"payvalue"} onChange={e => this.onChangePayMount(e, index)} type="number" className="form-control-sm col-sm-6"  min="1" step="0.01"></input>
```

En la funcion quiero que se valide que no se pueda escribir mas de 2 decimales en el input pero no se como, hasta ahora solo puedo validar que cuando se cumple la condición y se guarda en cap pero no se como hacer que en el input no se puedan escribir mas de 2 decimales

```
onChangePayMount(e, index){
    var cap = e.target.value;
    var patron = Number.parseFloat(e.target.value).toFixed(2);
    console.log(patron);
    cap = patron;
    }
}
```

Ya puedo hacer que cap guarde solo 2 decimales pero no se como hacer que el input no se pueda escribir mas de 2 digitos decimales

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres forzar a que el valor siempre tenga dos decimales, puedes hacer:

```
onChangePayMount(e) {
    e.target.value = Number.parseFloat(e.target.value).toFixed(2);
}
```

Con:

```
<input id={"IDpayvalue"} name={"payvalue"} onChange={this.onChangePayMount} type="number" className="form-control-sm col-sm-6"  min="1" step="0.01"></input>
```

Pero es un poco *agresivo* con el usuario, algo más amigable sería usar:

```
onChangePayMount(e) {
    e.target.value = Number.parseFloat(e.target.value).toFixed(2);
}
```

Con:

```
<input id={"IDpayvalue"} name={"payvalue"} onBlur={this.onChangePayMount} type="number" className="form-control-sm col-sm-6"  min="1" step="0.01"></input>
```

De esta manera el valor se corrige luego de que el `input` deja de ser usado y por lo tanto el usuario puede digitar el número que quiera, sin que se le corrija instantáneamente.

Comment: en teoria funciona pero tambien se realizan algunas validaciones mas en tiempo real y he visto que no se setea de nuevo el valor cuando se pierde el foco en el input, mas bien necesito que el usuario no pueda escribir mas de 2 decimales